# Wordpress: How can I add url GET parameter to my main menu items

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, menu, parameters

I'm trying to add a URL GET parameter to one of my main menu items in Wordpress(but I don't know how to). So, my approach was to detect a click event on the menu item, then pass a parameter via AJAX to my php page which will process value passed as needed.

My main questions are, looking at my code, how come is not working? is there a better way of doing this in WordPress and not rely on javascript?

Here is the javascript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#menu-item-128").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'homepage.php',
                        type: "GET",
                        data: ({ homeclick = true }),
                        success: function() {
                           alert("success!");
                        }
                    });
                 });
             });
       </script>
```

Here is my PHP:

```php
$homeclick = $_GET['homeclick'];   

if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['hs_user'] ) ) {
    get_header();
} elseif (isset( $_COOKIE['hs_user'] ) && $homeclick == true ) {
    get_header();
} else {
    // Do Something else
    header('Location: homepage-returning-users');        
}
```

Comment: This syntax is not right `({ homeclick = true })`. Also I would suggest you use WordPress hooks to add what you want to the menu items. If you're using `wp_nav_menu` there are various hooks: `wp_nav_menu`, `wp_nav_menu_objects`, `wp_nav_menu_class`, etc...

Comment: @brasofilo thanks for you feedback. My menu item is <ul><li><a href="www.somedomain.com">Home<li></ul>. I want to add a GET parameter just like you did but I don't know how to do in WP. Any examples you can share?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The filter hook `wp_get_nav_menu_items` is used to manipulate the Nav Menus. The `post_title` used in the example is the title of the Menu (Navigation Label), not of the post/page.

[image: home nav menu]

Drop this code in your `functions.php` file, adjust the `post_title` and `?my_var=test` to your needs. Note that better than `functions` is to [create your own plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 11, 3 );

function nav_items( $items, $menu, $args ) 
{
    if( is_admin() )
        return $items;

    foreach( $items as $item ) 
    {
        if( 'Home' == $item->post_title)
            $item->url .= '?my_var=test';

    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: That worked great!!! Thank you very much! One quick question: what do the numbers 11 and 3 represent in add_filter(); ?

Comment: `11` is the priority (1 is the highest, 10 the default). `3` is the number of parameters (items,menu,args). Please, see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/185667)

Comment: Just note that to see this "Navigation Label" and "Title Attributes" or "Classes" you have to check first the options on the top "Screen Options" button of Wordpress Admin menu... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting to pass a boolean value in your Ajax call with the variable `homeclick`. GET requests simply use text because the data is passed thru the URL, so if you are wanting a logical/boolean type you can use either "true" and "false" in text or perhaps 0 and 1. Also you have a syntax error, see below.

Try the following:

In you ajax call, fix the syntax as well as set homeclick to "true" as follows:
`data: ({ homeclick: 'true' }),`.

And in your php, change the if condition for variable `$homeclick` as follows:
`$homeclick == 'true'`.

You may want to consider using a POST method if you want to utilize a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use custom menus in Appearance>Menus. It will help you to retain custom URLs with get parameters. You may read it here [Wordpress Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen)

Answer (score 0):

That's a fork from Brasofilo that works perfectly for me:
(Put this code on your theme functions.php)

```
// Transform title attributes to parameters
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 11, 3 );
function nav_items( $items, $menu, $args )
{
    if( is_admin() )
        return $items;
    foreach( $items as $item )
    {
    if ($item->attr_title != "") $item->url .= '#' . $item->attr_title;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

What I'm doing here is to get the attributes of the menu-item and transform them to an anchor name. This way I will have this type of URL's: www.domain.com/my-page#anchor1

After this I just need to do some jQuery magic to jump (progressive scroll down) to the anchor. ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/bstrilziw/pen/AIoqs)).

If you cannot see the 'Title Attribute' input field just be sure to check the options on the top "Screen Options" button of Wordpress Admin menu...