# How to modify url in wp_nav_menu?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
            'depth' => 1,
            'container' => 'div',
            'link_before'     => '',
            'link_after'      => '',
        )
);
```

and this give me:

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-1">
        <a href="http://link1">link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
        <a href="http://link2">link2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-3">
        <a href="http://link3">link3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but I want to replace url in links from:

```
"http://link*"
```

to:

```
"javascript:myfunc('http://link*')";
```

How to do it?

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery or must it be done on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Well I thought I'd give this a go using PHP [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML as a string and replace the href attribute's value.

```
$content = '
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1">
            <a href="http://link1">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2">
            <a href="http://link2">link2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-3">
            <a href="http://link3">link3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
';

// New Dom Object
$dom = new DomDocument;

// Load $content as string
$dom->loadHTML($content);

// Get only a elements
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

// Loop through each a element and get it's href value
for ($n = 0; $n < $elements->length; $n++) {
    $item = $elements->item($n);

    // Get old href val
    $old_href = $item->getAttribute('href');

    // New href val
    $new_href = 'javascript:myfunc(\''.$old_href.'\')';

    // Replace old href with new
    $content = str_replace($old_href,$new_href,$content);
}

// Print results
echo $content;
```

Comment: I tried with the filter [`wp_get_nav_menu_items `](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18744287/1287812), but it's stripping the JavaScript out. Wrapping all this code in a function and it's a very nice solution for this and other similar cases. +1

Comment: @brasofilo Ah now that's interesting. The link to your solution looks sane enough to me - I wonder why it strips the JS?

Comment: I believe it runs a `esc_url_raw` on the link, in `wp-includes/nav-menu.php`. There's an action hook, `wp_update_nav_menu_item`, that could be of use, but I'll let this to another occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your functions.php file, which hooks into WP Core with the wp_nav_menu_objects filter hook.

```
function modify_nav_url($items) {
    $old_url = "http://link*";
    $new_url = "javascript:myfunc('http://link*')";

    foreach($items as $item){
        $item->url = str_replace($old_url, $new_url, $item->url);
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'modify_nav_url');
```

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137732/change-menu-items-url