# Changing URL's in wp_nav_menu Wordpress+Symfony

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, wp-nav-menu-item

In my symfony project I'm trying to use wordpress for free user-friendly content manager. My problem is, when I'm trying to take Wordpress menu, like:

```
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu_id'   => 'top-menu',
    ) );
```

Ofcourse menu items links to URL's like:

```
/wordpressfolder/page-item
```

And the point is: how to change it to:

```
/somethinganother/page-item
```

?

I want to do that, because I've changed the standard CMS routing, so I need to be consequent, that the project can look professional.

Ofcourse I'dont mind the js option because it's obvious, but I want to do it on server site if it is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify url in wp\_nav\_menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785155/how-to-modify-url-in-wp-nav-menu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one of the filters WordPress comes with. The following code example shows a way you could use.

```
function mmn_main_item_rewrite( $items, $args ) 
{
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $item->url = str_replace( 'wordpressfolder', 'somethinganother', $item->url );
    }

    return $items;
} 
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'mmn_main_item_rewrite', 10, 2 );
```

Just add this piece of code in the functions.php file in your active WordPress theme folder. Always use WordPress child themes for individual changes.

More details about the wp_nav_menu_objects hook in the WordPress documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_objects/

Comment: This answer solved a major problem for me. Thank you