# Wordpress - using variable in menu URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to use php variable in menu URL, that I defined in `function.php`?

This is actually not working:

[image]

For example, in variable `$path` I store username of every user so they can visit their own profile.

Comment: Short answer: No, it's not possible. That url is just for text. It doesn't evaluate PHP code there.

Comment: What is the value of $path? Why don't you just put the value there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hook and add the PHP programmatically.

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 11, 3 );
function nav_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {

     if( is_admin() )
        return $items;

    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        if( 'profil' == $item->post_title ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $username = $current_user->user_login;
            $item->url .= '/' . $username;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

I found this code from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731750/wordpress-how-can-i-add-url-get-parameter-to-my-main-menu-items) on this community.

Comment: yea i got username already stored i just need to attach it to profile link

Answer (score 0):

> **In Wordpress You Can Do Direct Like this for get the current user details:**

```
<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

> **Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user**

Comment: yea i got username already stored i just need to attach it to profile link

Comment: `url/users/<?=  echo '$current_user->user_login';  ?>`

Comment: actually this is what i wrote above that is not working